# how to querySelector children (only) from an element?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Imagine a structure like this:

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="firstdiv">...</div>
  <div class="important">...</div>
  <div id="lastdiv">
    <div id="subdiv">...</div>
    <div class="important">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if I write:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#boxes > div:not([class])')
```

I will get `#firstdiv` and `#lastdiv`. Great.

But what if I want to do the same from the `#boxes` element?

```
const boxes = document.querySelector('#boxes')

// this is what I tried
boxes.querySelectorAll('> div:not([class])') // it doesn't work

// and if I type
boxes.querySelectorAll('div:not([class])')
// I get #firstdiv, #lastdiv BUT ALSO #subdiv which I don't want
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:scope` to reference the element the `querySelectorAll` is being called on:

```js
const collection = boxes.querySelectorAll(':scope > div:not([class])');
console.log(collection.length, collection[0], collection[1]);
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="firstdiv">...</div>
  <div class="important">...</div>
  <div id="lastdiv">
    <div id="subdiv">...</div>
    <div class="important">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(unfortunately, it doesn't have [great](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility) browser support, though)

Comment: `great browser support` - edge/IE ... who cares :p

Comment: I didn't expect this to be so easy. That'll do. Thanks a lot

Comment: @vdegenne: Well, it's supposed to be *easier* - your original attempt of `boxes.querySelectorAll('> div:not([class])')` would have worked if browsers got on with it and implemented relative selectors already.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from `:scope` which sadly doesn't have good browser support, several options for you in two main categories:

### Filtering `children`

You could just filter [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) using [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(boxes.children, child => child.matches("div:not([class])"));
```

Live Example:

```js
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(boxes.children, child => child.matches("div:not([class])"));
for (const child of collection) {
    console.log(child.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="firstdiv">...</div>
  <div class="important">...</div>
  <div id="lastdiv">
    <div id="subdiv">...</div>
    <div class="important">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That does have to parse the selector each time. If it's really as simple as the selector shown, you might just write the parts individually:

```
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    boxes.children,
    child => child.tagName === "DIV" && child.getAttribute("class") === null
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    boxes.children,
    child => child.tagName === "DIV" && child.getAttribute("class") === null
);
for (const child of collection) {
    console.log(child.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="firstdiv">...</div>
  <div class="important">...</div>
  <div id="lastdiv">
    <div id="subdiv">...</div>
    <div class="important">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're okay with allowing it to match `<div id="foo" class>` elements (e.g., they have the attribute, but it's empty), then it's a bit simpler:

```
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    boxes.children,
    child => child.tagName === "DIV" && !child.className
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    boxes.children,
    child => child.tagName === "DIV" && !child.className
);
for (const child of collection) {
    console.log(child.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="firstdiv">...</div>
  <div class="important">...</div>
  <div id="lastdiv">
    <div id="subdiv">...</div>
    <div class="important">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Filtering `querySelectorAll` result

**Or**, filter out the matches you don't want after the fact:

```
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    boxes.querySelectorAll("div:not([class])"),
    child => child.parentNode === boxes
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const collection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    boxes.querySelectorAll("div:not([class])"),
    child => child.parentNode === boxes
);
for (const child of collection) {
    console.log(child.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="firstdiv">...</div>
  <div class="important">...</div>
  <div id="lastdiv">
    <div id="subdiv">...</div>
    <div class="important">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also a very clean solution and readable syntax. I appreciate the effort of your answer. Thank you sir.